# Callback function beginner

Tags: jquery, callback

I'm practicing with a callback function but it doesn't seem to work.
I want my h1 element to fade in and then when that's done fade out.

html:

```
<h1 id="randomid"> Fade in</h1>
```

script:

```
$("#randomid").hide();
$("#randomid").fadeIn({

}, 5000,
function(){
$("#randomid").fadeOut(5000);
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra empty object as your first parameter to `fadeIn()` (`{ }`).  Remove that and just pass the timing and the callback:

```
$("#randomid").fadeIn(5000,
  function(){
    $("#idie").fadeOut(5000);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is bad, because it's `fadeIn(duration, callback)` so:

```
$("#randomid").fadeIn( 5000, function(){
   $("#idie").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P7mLA/)

Answer (score 0):

If that's your complete HTML, then it's not working because there is no element matching the selector `#idie` in the DOM. You're also using the incorrect syntax for [`fadeIn(duration, callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

```
$("#randomid").hide();
$("#randomid").fadeIn(5000,
    function(){
        $("#randomid").fadeOut(5000);
    }
);
```